# Refresh data vb

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, highcharts

trying to implement the RegisterClientScriptBlock to my vb.net code, using the highchart javascript code.

so far i have this.

```
      Dim script As String
    script = _
    "var chart = $('#container1').highcharts();" & _
    "chart.redraw();"

    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock( _
        Me, _
        GetType(Page), _
        "container1", _
        script, _
        True)
```

i need to refresh the data.

am trying to use the above method to re fresh data using my arrays:

```
    hidden.Value = arrayJson
    hidden1.Value = arrayJson1
    hidden2.Value = arrayJson2
    hidden3.Value = arrayJson3
    hidden4.Value = arrayJson4
    hidden5.Value = arrayJson5
    hidden6.Value = arrayJson6
    hidden7.Value = arrayJson7
```

not sure how to link it up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with VB, but you can use a similar approach as I did with Java:

1. create a plaholder HTML page including jquery 1.7 or later and hightcharts
2. include some wrapper javascript that will ease interaction with your code:

See: http://jsfiddle.net/avitry/5bZ6n/2/

```
var chartList = new Array();
function newChart(properties, cid) {
    $("#container").append("<div id ='" + cid + "' class='chart'></div>");
    var jprops = properties.data; // adapt to your data storage
    var defaultOptions = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: cid,
        },
        plotOptions: {
            line: {
                enableMouseTracking: true,
                allowPointSelect: true
            }
        }
    };

    // Merge options from the properties object provided and defaultOptions
    $.extend(jprops, defaultOptions);
    // Create chart
    var nChart = new Highcharts.Chart(jprops);
    // Add to the list
    chartList[cid] = nChart;
}

// Remove all charts and empty the container
function clear() {
    chartList.length = 0;
    $("#container").empty();
}

// Redraw this chart
function refresh(cid) {
    chartList[cid].redraw();
}
```

3 . call the javascript wrapper function 
You should call "newchart( ChartDataObject, String/id)" from your code:

```
// Call newChart(json object, string) from your code
// This is called automatically onload for this demo
$(function () {
    newChart({
        data: {
            chart: {
                type: 'line',
                inverted: true
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
            },
            series: [{
                data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
            }]
        }
    }, "chart-1");

    refresh("chart-1");
    //clear();
});
```

You basically pass json data to the function newChart() which is responsible for calling Highcharts functions and set default options. This makes it easier to design your page in a browser and removes boiler plate from your code.

If generating an object as I did in the fiddle is too difficult, you may add as many helper functions as needed, using the string id to refer to your chart object: newChart("chart1); setTitle("chart1", "My Title"), setData("[1, 2, 3]") and so on.

The .Net framework has Json serializer build in: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179.aspx. You'll have better chances using an existing json serializer.

Alain

Comment: What I wrote here is plain javascript. The way to solve the problem is the same in VB or java. Consider using a highlevel framework if fiddling with javascript sounds too difficult. See the other answer below.

Comment: i just had 2 little code, and you given me a big code, so which goes on the code behind to refresh the data

Comment: i think this is the problem, i am missing something here.

Dim script As String
    script = _
    "function chart()" & _
     "  {" & _
    "chart.redraw();" & _
    " }" & _
          ";"

Comment: You don't provide enough information: How your charts are hooked to your script. If you know how you would call your scripts within firebug or the like, then you're one step closer to know what to call from VB. Is the chart to redraw selected ? Do you get an error ? It can help to hook Firebug lite to your page in order to see what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler approach could be to use a wrapper to Highcharts such as http://dotnethighcharts.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

Scripts passed using `RegisterClientScriptBlock` [need `<script>` tags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btf44dc9.aspx):

```
Dim script As String
script = _
"<script type='text/javascript'>var chart = $('#container1').highcharts();" & _
"chart.redraw();</script>"

ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock( _
    Me, _
    GetType(Page), _
    "container1", _
    script, _
    True)
```